# HTTP to HTTPS nginx flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, nginx, http, flask

Недавно перешел в веб .

Нужна помощь в переадресации с HTTP на HTTPS .

Думаю эта информация понадобится :

Сайт на питоне (фреймворк flask) , порт 5000 , [хостинг](https://cp.vdsina.ru/) , nginx .

На данный момент сайт не имеет домен .

Код :

```
from func import *

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    return main()

@app.route('/<string:film>', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def find_(film):
    return result(film)

app.run(debug = True,port=5000,host="0.0.0.0")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    return "main"

@app.route('/film', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def film():
    return "film"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True, port=5000, host="localhost", ssl_context='adhoc') #добавьте ssl_context='adhoc'
```

Только у вас сертификата не будет.

Comment: Где можно свой ssl сертификат создать ?

Comment: @Gadzhi11 https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-your-flask-application-over-https на этом сайте указано как это сделать, найдите где описывают openssl

Comment: Спасибо , если будут вопросы задам завтра .
Помечу ответ , как принятый когда закончу .

Comment: эффективнее делать редирект на уровне nginx т.к. это не требует инстанцирования приложения и будет значительно быстрее. Если покажете текущий конфиг nginx, то смогу подсказать какие нужны изменения для редиректа

Comment: htaccess ещё можно подправить )

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы создать ssl сертификат я использовал эти команды (nginx ubuntu 20.4) :

`pip3 install certbot-nginx`

`sudo certbot --nginx`

Для обновления сертификата :

`sudo certbot renew --dry-run`

Все ключи находятся в этой директории :

`/etc/letsencrypt/live/{domain.com}/`